JMSCC0111: IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to set a pre-existing client ID on a Connection or JMSContext
I am seeing the below error even after I specify the subscriber client id in the the properties file. I am using Spring Boot 3.3.4
2024-10-28T15:47:30.173-04:00  WARN 14156 --- [(2)-10.1.81.174] o.s.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator  : JMS health check failed
com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedInvalidClientIDException: JMSCC0111: IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to set a pre-existing client ID on a Connection or JMSContext.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:334) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:126) ~[com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client-9.3.3.0.jar:9.3.3.0 - p933-L230531]

Below is how my application.properties file look like
ibm.mq.queue-manager=${MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER}
ibm.mq.topicName=${MQ_TOPIC_NAME}
ibm.mq.channel=${MQ_CHANNEL}
ibm.mq.connName=${MQ_HOSTNAME}
ibm.mq.user=${MQ_USERNAME}
ibm.mq.password=${MQ_PASSWORD}
ibm.mq.application-name=${MQ_SUBSCRIBER_NAME}
ibm.mq.client-id=${MQ_SUBSCRIBER_CLIENT_ID}

Connection details are accurate and client-id passed and which is unique as well.
Below is my MQ connection configuration file:
import com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConfigurationProperties;
import com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer;
import com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQConnectionFactoryFactory;
import jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MQConnectionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("ibm.mq")
    public MQConfigurationProperties ibmProductConfigProperties() {
        return new MQConfigurationProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(final MQConfigurationProperties properties,
                                                         ObjectProvider<List<MQConnectionFactoryCustomizer>> factoryCustomizers) {
        return new MQConnectionFactoryFactory(properties, factoryCustomizers.getIfAvailable()).createConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                              DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}

Below I have added gradle dependencies as well
implementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:4.3.2.RELEASE")
implementation("javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0.1")
implementation 'com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:3.1.2'

How do I get rid of the above error?

This is the relevant portion of the error:
JMSCC0111: IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to set a pre-existing client ID on a Connection or JMSContext.

This message is telling you that you are setting a client ID on your JMS Connection (or JMSContext) that is already in use.
The JMS specification mandates that client IDs must be unique for each Connection/JMSContext. Therefore, you need to change your ibm.mq.client-id value so that it unique across all clients connecting to the JMS broker.

I do have a unique client id supplied, still I see this error message though!

If you still see the same error message then the broker still thinks there are multiple connections using the same client ID. Could Spring be spinning up more than one connection?

Below statement what I added in application.properties file to get rid of this error
management.health.jms.enabled=false

This kind of blind folds this error and the subscriber should still be able to receive incoming messages

This configuration disables the JmsHealthIndicator which is creating a JMS connection using the same client ID as your application.

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "blind folds"?
